# mongoexport / mongodump with option --uri

Tags: mongodb, mongodump, mongoexport, mongodb-tools

During my studying of MongoDB I tried to dump a collection from training course's mongo database.
I tried both `mongodump` and `mongoexport`.
My shell command is like

```
mongoexport --uri="mongodb://<my-username>:<my_password>@<replica-1>.mongodb.net:27017,<replica-2>.mongodb.net:27017,<replica-3>.mongodb.net:27017/<database>?replicaSet=<replica-set>" --collection=<collection-name> --out=<collection-name>.json --ssl
```

When I run the command, nothing happened: no response, no new local files, no errors, only cursor flashes.

How can I export collections **by the uri**?

Comment: Please run the command with `--verbose` and paste the output here

Comment: @tbhaxor, both `mongodump` and `mongoexport` were tried with `--verbose`. The same result: nothing happened, cursor flashed only.

Comment: Maybe you need to specify the authentication database, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470

Answer (score 0):

```
--forceTableScan
```

option can be used along with mongodump & --uri option

> mongodump --uri
> mongodb+srv://<user_name>:@.mongodb.net/db_name
> --forceTableScan --collection <collection_name> --out ./dump/